# JSF SelectManyCheckbox ajax render id

Tags: jsf

I have

```
<h:panelGroup>
     <ui:repeat value="#{requests.filters}" var="filter">
          <custom:filter filter="#{filter}" update="j_requests"/>
     </ui:repeat>
     <h:panelGroup id="j_requests">
     <h:outputText value="Запросы журналистов:"/>
     <custom:requestList id="allrequests" data="#{requests.getRequests()}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and it works fine on localhost computer but on other computer loading of page fail with exception: `avax.faces.FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'j_requests' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt20_filters` 
it seems that j_requests is not visible inside ui:repeat? but how it works on develop machine?
here is filter composite component:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="update"/>
    <cc:attribute name="filter" type="ru.rs.corhub.web.filters.RegionBoxFilter"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.filter.name}:"/>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox id="#{cc.attrs.id}_filters" value="#{cc.attrs.filter.selectedCriterias}" converter="regionConverter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.filter.criterias}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.value()}" itemValue="#{item}"/>
            <f:ajax render="#{cc.attrs.update}" listener="#{requests.populateFilteredList()}"/>
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:form>
</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: Try to put the id as absolute id, i.e. `update=":j_requests"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a `h:form` - which is a NamingContainer - inside your custom component all the ids of the elements inside get prefixed with the id of that form. So when you put an relative id into `update`-property the component will not be found, because there is not component with id `j_requests` inside that form. To overcome this you can use an absolute id by prefixing the id with `:`, i.e. `update=":j_requests"`.